# Trouble running p1pp - GLI.run no longer works for GLI-2

Tags: ruby, xmpp, publish-subscribe, gli-gem

I am new to ruby, wanted to try out the ProcessOne's Push Platform (p1pp)

I've downloaded the source for p1pp (from https://github.com/processone/p1pp), tried running it in Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$./bin/p1.rb
```

Got the error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- gli (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from ./bin/p1.rb:16
```

installed gli using the command

```
gem install gli
```

This time I got

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- blather/client/dsl (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/krishna/PubSub/p1pp-master/lib/p1pp/p1_publisher.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from ./bin/p1.rb:18
```

Installed blather:

```
gem install blather
```

Now I am stuck here:

```
You should include GLI::App instead
GLI.run no longer works for GLI-2, you must just call `run(ARGV)' instead
either fix your app, or use the latest GLI in the 1.x family
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself!

include GLI::App instead of GLI and change "exit GLI.run(ARGV)" in the last line to "exit run(ARGV)

Found this info here:

[1] http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/200/topics/10975

[2] https://github.com/bencevans/hnews/issues/3